# tmTheme files for LaTeX

Tags: textmate, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for `.thTheme` files for LaTeX.

The `.tmTheme` files are used (amongst other) by TextMate to specify the colors of syntax-highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Collections

- [Textmate Themes](https://github.com/textmate/themes.tmbundle): [Theme Files](https://github.com/textmate/themes.tmbundle/tree/master/Themes)
- [Collection of TextMate Themes by filmgirl](https://github.com/filmgirl/TextMate-Themes): [Theme Files](https://github.com/filmgirl/TextMate-Themes)

## Single Themes

- [idleFingers](https://github.com/textmate/idlefingers_textmate_theme): [Theme File](https://github.com/textmate/idlefingers_textmate_theme/blob/master/Themes/idleFingers.tmTheme)
- [Prospettiva](https://github.com/textmate/Prospettiva-Theme): [Theme File](https://github.com/textmate/Prospettiva-Theme/blob/master/Themes/Prospettiva.tmTheme)
- [Rainbow Dash](https://github.com/sanssecours/Rainbow-Dash.tmbundle): [Theme File](https://github.com/sanssecours/Rainbow-Dash.tmbundle/blob/master/Themes/Rainbow%20Dash.tmTheme)

Comment: Do you know if there are special requirements for a theme if I want to use it for Latex syntax-highlighting?

Comment: I found in your list a specific theme whose name is `ForLaTeX.tmTheme`

Comment: All themes should work fine for LaTeX highlighting too. A theme defines styles for certain [TextMate grammar](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) scopes. You can check the current scope of a LaTeX command/environment by pressing `^` + `⇧` + `P` inside a TextMate document.

Comment: In the theme I'm using right now, the text between `$` isn't highlighted. Thanks for you help ;-)

Comment: Strange, usually code between `$` signs should be highlighted. For example, if I use the [Rainbow Dash theme](https://github.com/sanssecours/Rainbow-Dash.tmbundle), then the `$` sign and the `+` sign in the code `$1 + 2$` are highlighted in green (scope `string.other.math.tex`). The numbers use the color purple (scope `constant.numeric.math.tex`).

Comment: So far, I have only tried with a theme called Tomorrow. I am testing the themes with [SyntaxKit](https://github.com/colasbd/SyntaxKit/branches) .